# Удалить ссылку из текста

Tags: php, url

Как можно удалить такую ссылку https://site.com/7e1cJk из текста

Comment: Конкретно эту ссылку или ссылку любую?

Comment: Достаточно такого варианта: `echo preg_replace('~https?://\S+~', '', 'ссылка и https://site.com/7e1cJk текст');`

Answer (score 3):

```
$url = 'Здесь http://site.com/7e1-cJk6 555 простой текст';
$url = preg_replace('#https?://(.*?) #i', '', $url);
echo $url;
```

Comment: если в конце ссылки слеш (/) - preg_replace('#http(s)?://(.*)\b(/)?#i', ' ', $url);

Comment: У вас он удаляет всё и после ссылки

Comment: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/gB

Comment: @Walfter, да нет вроде, на 5.6 и 7.2 после ссылки все на месте

Comment: Вы посмотрите внимательней у вас если после ссылки пробел потом цифры   то именно эти цифры он удалит

Comment: Я же даже линк дал

Comment: @Walfter, с цифрами что то не ладит, после \b добавил пробел, все отобразилось

Comment: У вас просто регулярка не правильно построена https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/gC посмотрите первый ответ

Comment: Вот по первому ответу https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/gD

Comment: Вот=)) Только меняйте не на пробел а на ничего=) `''` а то у вас несколько пробелов в строке получается=)

Comment: И `(s)?` вот такая конструкция ради символа не обязательна `s?`

Comment: @Walfter, ок, понял, спасибки)

Comment: Стресс тест обоих регулярок https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/gF

Answer (score 2):

```
$TEXT = '123 https://site.com/7e1cJk 123';
$TEXT = str_replace('https://site.com/7e1cJk', '', $TEXT);
var_dump($TEXT);
```

Как-то изи, но если нужно удалить любые ссылки, то как-то так:

```
$TEXT = '123 https://site.com/7e1cJk 123';
$TEXT = preg_replace('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', '', $TEXT);
var_dump($TEXT);
```

Comment: Однозначно плюс!=)))) XD

Comment: @Walfter :D было с кого брать пример

Comment: А если просто http будет?=)

Comment: @Walfter `http://site.ru` - проглотит, если просто `http` - то это обычный текст, который не является ссылкой.

Comment: Извиняюсь=) ? не увидел